# Why isn't a Task awaited before it get's cancelled?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I need to write a service with some complex behaviour like simultanious tasks and I'm facing an issue with.

I've written a sample in xUnit to show you the problem.

1 want to execute a task on a background, eventually start some child tasks.
At a moment in time the task needs to be cancelled.

Therefore, I have the following in place:

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldWaitUnitTaskCompleted()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Task.Delay(10000).Wait();
            TaskIsCompleted = true;
        }
    }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    Thread.Sleep(3000);

    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

    Assert.True(TaskIsCompleted);
}
```

}

However, the xUnit completes after 3 seconds (my thread sleep).
In my task, I'm having a loop that say, as long as it's not a cancellation request delay if for 10 second.

So the behaviour I expect would be:

- Start the application.
- Start the task (since it's no cancellation request, a delay of 10 seconds will start).
- Wait for 3 seconds and then cancel the token.
- Wait for the task with the 10 second delay to complete and then exit.

Why doesn't my code wait for the 10 seconds frame to pass?

Comment: No background threads could exist when the main (foreground) thread had already exit after 3 seconds. Your app died already. You would have to Thread.Sleep the main thread for another 7+ seconds to resume other work.

Answer (score 4):

You don't `await` your `Task` which you create. Hence the execution of the code just continues on to the `Thread.Sleep(3000)`.

Answer (score 2):

`Cancel` signals that cancellation has been requested.

It *doesn't* wait for all tasks to complete before allowing the cancelling code to carry on doing useful things - if you *do* want to wait for those tasks to respond, there are already mechanisms for you to do this, separately. So `Cancel` just does one job, and does it well.

Comment: And what are these mechanisms?

Comment: @Complexity - `Task.Wait` (or `await`) for a single task. `Task.WaitAll` or `Task.WhenAll` for multiple tasks - depends on how you want to structure the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to dive into this. It was driving me nuts but you made it clear for me :-)